# How to carry the same wifi connection from one activity to another

Tags: android, wifi

I have connected some WiFi pragmatically in One activity and I need same connection in another activity. I don't want to disconnect wifi connections while switching from activity to another.

Here is the code to connect to wifi ,

```
WifiInfo connInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (null != connInfo) {
       //connect to previous network

    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();

    wifiConfig.SSID = "\"" + prefSSID + "\"";
    wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    otvNetworkID = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(otvNetworkID, true);
    wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
```

Comment: Please provide your wifi  connection code.

Comment: @vishalk I added the code.

Comment: @Archana make a separate class for making the WIFI connection. Use a static method and pass a Global context to it, not an activity context.

Comment: @SharpEdge Am doing the same. The above code is part of it. I am not getting how to carry the same connection to next activity.

Comment: @Archana apply the singleton pattern here, it is best suited for your logic.. Make a single static private connection in  a separate class and then get the connection from anywhere